# How do I geolocate an image returned by the 'map image' API?

Tags: geolocation, here-api

The HERE Maps (the old Nokia Maps) has a variety of APIs, the most useful of which for non-web desktop applications looks like the [Map Image API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image).  This API allows you to specify a [center location and a zoom level to get an image](http://developer.here.com/enterprise/docs/map_image/topics/examples.html), along with an image size.

**How do you georeference the returned image?**  The image is specified by center and zoom level, not by a bounding box or corner coordinates.  If you need to display the map image as the background to other, geolocated data, how do find the coordinates of the image corners in order to render the map correctly?

My guess is that you can do so by using the zoom level, so, for example, a square image of any pixel size at a specific zoom level would have specific real-world dimensions.  However, this is only a guess. The [API documentation](http://developer.here.com/enterprise/docs/map_image/topics/api-reference.html) doesn't seem to have any content addressing georeferencing the map results at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the `nomrk` parameter and add two hidden poi markers for the top-left and bottom-right corners - as in this example of the [Strait of Dover](http://image.maps.cit.api.here.com/mia/1.6/mapview?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&nord=&poi=50%2C1%2C51%2C3&nomrk=&h=256&w=256) across the English Channel. [50N,2E - 51N,3E]

Ideally since the maps use the normalized Mercator projection, you should specify `h` and `w` to be the same value and keep the number of degrees latitude requested = number of degrees longitude requested. This will ensure that the POIs are in the corners of the map.

As an alternative, there is also the [Map Tile API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile) (log-in required), which uses standard Tile Map Service (**TMS**) addressing techniques. You can calculate the required tile using the following (sample code is in Java)

```
 public void calculatePosition(int latitude, int longitude, int zoom) {
         int p= Math.pow(2, zoom); double x= longitude /Math.PI; x=(x+1)/2;
         double y= latitude/Math.PI; y = (log(tan(pi/4.0+latitude/2.0))+1)/2; y = 1 - y;
         int column=(int) x*p; int row=(int)y*p;
         System.out.println("[zoom,col,row] = " + zoom + "," + col+ "," + row);
 }
```

Comment: That looks great - and in fact the Tile Map API looks perfect. Thankyou!

Comment: And (sorry) would you mind giving me an upvote, please? I need 5 rep in this tag to suggest some edits and the tag synonym, and I haven't asked a question about Nokia / Here maps before.